# Is there a way to limit bandwidth per ip using HTB + a CIDR range in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, traffic-shaping, tc, htb

I can create rules to limit a entire subnet or to limit individual ip addresses with tc and htb.  I am looking to use CIDR ranges to keep things somewhat elegant.

The machines in question are all running CentOS 7.  I have been attempting to use tc + htb to accomplish this, but I am open to other tools if there is a better method.

My goal is to limit by a CIDR range and assign individual limits per source ip address.

For example, set global limit for 192.168.1.0/24 to 100Mb/s and each source ip within 192.168.1.0/24 has a individual upload limit of 10Mb/s that may not be exceeded.

Here is a working example of what I am doing for each ip(looking to simplify procedure if possible):

These steps only need to be performed once:

```
Create initial HTB qdisc:
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12       

Create root class:
# tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit ceil 100mbit

These steps must be performed for each IP in the CIDR range using current method (what I am looking to hopefully improve):

A class must be added for each source ip:
# tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 10mbit ceil 100mbit
# tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate 10mbit ceil 100mbit
# tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 10mbit ceil 100mbit

A filter must be created for each source ip:
# tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.2 flowid 1:10
# tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.3 flowid 1:11
```

It may be that there is no elegant way to do this, but any tips / advice would be greatly appreciated.  I have looked through several guides online such as http://lartc.org.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try with hash, giving one bucket per ip to provide an equal amount of pps per ip.
You should use a sfq qdisc too, since htb is not a fair one.

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit ceil 100mbit
# Here, you want a fair qdisc
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 101: sfq perturb 10
# Put a range in the filter
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.0/24 flowid 1:1
# Create 254 bucket, each ip src will be attached to one bucket
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:1 protocol ip handle 10 flow hash keys nfct-src divisor 254
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can find here: [Linux Firewall mark classifier (tc-fw) not working after upgrade to Debian 9 - kernel 4.19](https://serverfault.com/questions/1043976/linux-firewall-mark-classifier-tc-fw-not-working-after-upgrade-to-debian-9-k) working configuration for your task.

Br,
Nikolay